# How to save .docx file into S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-docx

I am using python-docx to create document. I want to save this file to AWS S3. Currently what I am doing is, I am creating .docx file and saving it locally using `document.save('filename.docx')`. Then using `s3.meta.client.upload_file('/path/to/file/filename.docx', bucket, 'filename.docx')` to save it into S3. Is there any way where I can save .docx file directly into AWS S3 without saving it locally?

Comment: you could always use ```client.upload_fileobj()``` but not entirely sure if you could use it on ```document```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. As @ewong suggested, here is a sample code snippet:

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
from docx import Document

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
document = Document()
# ...

with BytesIO() as fileobj:
    document.save(fileobj)
    fileobj.seek(0)
    s3.upload_fileobj(fileobj, 'your-bucket-name', 'your/s3/key')
```